# What is the first transforming/morphing mobile suit/robot in anime?

Tags: tropes, gundam

I have watched all the Mobile Suit Gundam series and many other transforming robot genre series, but I want to know which is the first series that started the transforming/morphing mobile suit/robot genre in anime.

Here, transforming/morphing is changing from aircraft/armour to humanoid/creature form or any other forms.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga SE Charles. Please consider to expand your question i.e. clarifying what type of robots you're talking about.

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate of http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3828/1734

Comment: also this one... http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3629/1734

Comment: Super robots and morphing mobile suit are different fwik. If OP expands this question I cannot see a reason to close or mark as duplicate.

Comment: @ Here what i mean by transforming/morphing is changing from aircraft/armour to humanoid/creature form or any other forms

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you mean a giant robot that transforms into something else, usually a vehicle. If that's the case then you have two candidates depending on how further you want to specify them.

**Brave Raideen** was released in 1975 and it featured a giant robot that transformed into a bird shaped rocket ship.

[image]

[image]

**Getter Robo** was first released in 1974 and it featured three space ships that *combined* into a three different giant robots.

[image]

An honorable mention goes to **Ambassador Magma** which was first released in 1966. The titular character changed into a rocket ship, although there was no transforming mehcanism shown, so I (personally) wouldn't include him.

[image]

[image]